# Nginx SSL auth curtain client certificate

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate, certificate-authority

I have working Nginx with TLS authentication with following configuration. All request with valid client certificates will be terminated at Nginx and request will be forwarded to backend app.

```
    upstream app {
        server app:8080;
    }

    server {
        listen                 443 ssl;
        server_name            localhost;
        ssl_certificate        /etc/ssl/cert_example_com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key    /etc/ssl/cert_example_com.key;
        ssl_client_certificate /etc/ssl/ca.crt;
        ssl_protocols          TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
        ssl_ciphers            HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_verify_client      on;

        location / {
                proxy_pass         http://app;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header   Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header   Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
    }
```

With this configuration I want Nginx to authenticate only certain client certificates. This is because I am using Private RootCA to generate Type A certs and Type B certs. Type A certs are used with MQTT for auth & Type B certs are used for Nginx (`HTTPS`) authentication.

client certificate (Type A) for MQTT will be unique for each client `<UUID>.example.com`. client certificate (Type B) for Nginx will have name (DN) `base.example.com` & certificate will be shared among multiple clients. Aslo there will be limited number of Type B certificates active at a time with same name (DN) `base.example.com` and different certificate ID.

any help on this how I can possibly achieve this ?

Comment: How are the different types identifiable?

Comment: Is this name part of the certificate's DN, because you can access that value in Nginx by using the `$ssl_client_s_dn` variable.

Comment: Yes, DN will be `base.example.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the certificates will be validated, but you can still reject requests from connections using the other certificates by checking the DN of the client certificate.

For example:

```
server {
    if ($ssl_client_s_dn !~ \bbase\.example\.com\b) { return 403; }
    ...
}
```